# How to prevent the extra click when using jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery

I am using a toggle effect to display a slideshow which is functioning as a quick, visual selector for choosing beer manufacturers. An example of this can be found here:

http://srperrott.silverjerk.com/products/domestic/millercoors

The problem is, I have to effectively click the selected trigger twice in order for the toggle to take affect. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quick-brew-header").toggle(function(){
        $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:40},40);
    },function(){
        $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:165},40);
    });
});
```

And in my CSS I've declared that the starting height of .zone-preface-wrapper be 40px.

It seems there should be an easy fix for this. I definitely would appreciate any help in finding a resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the element starts at 40, your first argument animates to 40 - so you see no change.

By switching the two toggle handlers, you should see the change to 165 on the first click.

```
$(".quick-brew-header").toggle(
    function() {
        $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:165},40);
    },
    function() {
        $(".zone-preface-wrapper").animate({height:40},40);
    }
);
```

Comment: + 1 Man, you were fast. Let me at least add the fiddle, I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/zstzC/ :)

Comment: Brilliant Steve, thanks. And thanks insertusenamehere for the great fiddle example. This was baffling me. I am tragically uneducated in jQuery.

Comment: This may require an entirely new discussion, but I was considering the user experience while navigating these beer pages. I like the idea of the "Brew Selector" being hidden on page view. It makes sense to me to keep this experience succinct. However, when navigating away from the current page, is there any way to use Javascript to say, "Hey, I've selected an item from the Quick Brew Selector, now on the next page keep the selector open." If someone can take the time to navigate this menu a bit for me and confirm this is a desirable change and maybe put me on the right path with the code...thx

Comment: Thanks for the direction Steve, and again for the quick help!